# Is there a way in pandas to compare two values within one column and sum how many times the second value is greater?

Tags: pandas

In my pandas dataframe, I have one column, score, thats rows are values such as [80,100], [90,100], etc. what I want to do is go through this column and if the second value in the list is greater than the first value, then to count that. so that I have a value that sums the number of times where in [a,b], b was greater. how would I do this?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(len([x for x in df['score'] if x[1] > x[0]]))
```